# sorting by frequency and custom expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

Consider the following SQL table:

```
+------+------+
| kind | name |
+------+------+
| K1   | N1   |
| K2   | N21  |
| K2   | N22  |
| K3   | N31  |
| K3   | N32  |
| K3   | N33  |
| K4   | N4   |
+------+------+
```

I want to show this table sorted by the kind and name with the following ordering requirement for the kind. The kind K1 should always be first. The rest of kinds are sorted according to the number of names per kind from the most frequent to least frequent kind. I.e. the result should be sorted as:

```
+------+------+
| K1   | N1   |
| K3   | N31  |
| K3   | N32  |
| K3   | N33  |
| K2   | N21  |
| K2   | N22  |
| K4   | N4   |
+------+------+
```

Here K3 follows K1 since it is the most frequent kind. To do that under MySQL I came up with the following:

```
SELECT
    a.kind, a.name
FROM
    test a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT kind, count(*) AS freq FROM test GROUP BY kind) b
    ON a.kind = b.kind
ORDER BY
    a.kind <> 'K1', b.freq desc, a.name;
```

Is it a good way to do that? In particular, is using the nested select just to influence the sorting order is OK?

Comment: It is ok as long as you get your desired result. Becuase thats what you want as output. you cant compromise your ouput for query being ok or not.

Comment: I prefer `a.kind = 'K1' desc`, but your expression is fine.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve the same result but in my opinion you came up with the clearest way to do the query.

Answer (score 0):

After using the search in the production it turned out that the SQL I used in the proposed answer is not correct since the question is not correct either.

The problem is that if 2 kinds have the same frequencies, their sorting order will be a random and they could even intertwine each other. The correct question should have mentioned that if frequencies match, the kinds should be sorted alphabetically.

The answer for this corrected question including the suggesting by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) is:

```
 SELECT
    a.kind, a.name
FROM
    test a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT kind, count(*) AS freq FROM test GROUP BY kind) b
    ON a.kind = b.kind
ORDER BY
    a.kind = 'K1' desc, b.freq desc, a.kind, a.name;
```